# Issues in implementing Exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

I have a function named createBook. In the function, I ask the user to input the BookId and BookName. I want to implement exception handling here.

What I want here is that whenever any other character except int is entered in BookId (because it is of type int), then it should print "invalid bookid" and then again call the function createBook.

I tried doing it but I was encountering an infinite loop here. Can someone guide, please?

```
void create_book()
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"                                           ....CREATE NEW BOOK....\n\n\n";
        cout<<"                                               Enter book id no:\t";
        cin>>bid;
        cin.ignore();
        if(!isdigit(bid))
        {
            try{
            throw 10;
            }

            catch(int e){

                cout<<" Invalid bookid";
                create_book();

            }

        }

        cout<<"                                               Enter book name:\n";
        getline(cin, bname);
            for (int i = 0; i < bname.length(); i++) {
            bname[i] = toupper(bname[i]);
            }
        cout<<"                                               Enter author's name:\n";
        getline(cin, aname);
            for (int i = 0; i < aname.length(); i++) {
            aname[i] = toupper(aname[i]);
            }
        cout<<"\n                                               Book Type Menu:\n";
        cout<<"                                               1:  Course Book\n";
        cout<<"                                               2:  Reference Book\n";
        cout<<"                                               3:  Journals\n";
        cout<<"                                               4:  Research Papers\n";
        int b;
        do{
            cout<<"                                               Enter code for type of book:\t";
            cin>>b;
        }while(b<=0 || b>4);
        btype = static_cast<booktype>(b);
        cout<<"\n                                               Subject Menu:\n";
        cout<<"                                               1:   Physics\n";
        cout<<"                                               2:   Computer Science\n";
        cout<<"                                               3:   Electrical and electronics\n";
        cout<<"                                               4:   Chemistry\n";
        cout<<"                                               5:   Mathematics\n";
        cout<<"                                               6:   Literature\n";
        cout<<"                                               7:   Others\n";
        do{
            cout<<"                                     Enter code for subject of book:\t";
            cin>>b;
        }while(b<=0 || b>8);
        subject = static_cast<subjecttype>(b);
    }

    string return_book_type()
    {
    switch(btype){
        case 1: return("Course Book");
            break;
        case 2: return("Reference Book");
            break;
        case 3: return("Journals");
            break;
        case 4: return("Research Papers");
            break;
        default: return("NULL");
    }
    }

    string return_subject_name()
    {
    switch(subject){
        case 1: return("Physics");
            break;
        case 2: return("Computer Science");
            break;
        case 3: return("Electrical and electronics");
                break;
        case 4: return("Chemistry");
            break;
        case 5: return("Mathematics");
            break;
        case 6: return("Literature");
            break;
        case 7: return("Others");
            break;
        default: return("NULL");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Post what you did and we can comment; else it's just crystal ball magic at what you're doing wrong

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and learn how to use a debugger to step through your program line by line.

Comment: Exception Handling and Input Validations are different concepts though confused to be same by many. Exceptions should be handled for an exceptional condition only. Why don't you share what you have already done in your code?

Comment: I have posted the code now!

Comment: What part is creating the infinite loop? Which of the `while` loops is it?

Comment: It's the exception handling statements leading to an infinite loop